# Creating a personal exception to anti-magic?

Tags: dnd-5e, antimagic-field

Does anyone have any in-game knowledge of a way how to be able to create an object or some such that grants a character the ability to still cast/power magics while in a dead magic zone or anti magic field? One that specifically just works to only create a personal exception to the anti-magic for who has it.

I'm a caster in a campaign where the DM has introduced a series of antimagic/ dead magic scenarios.

Comment: Why are you looking for this? Stating why you are trying to find something will let answers *(a)* better understand what you are looking for, and/or *(b)* give an alternate solution to the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Because I'm a caster in a campaign where the DM has introduced a series of antimagic/ dead magic scenarios. I would like to see if anyone has ever researched this sort of thing ingame, and how they went about it, hopefully so that i may emulate successfully.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we don't do "idea generation" or "brainstorm" questions; these are too broad.

Comment: Are you specifically asking what **official** (rules-legal) ways there are to still use magic in an *antimagic field*? If you are, you should edit your question to make that clear; I think that is an answerable question (albeit probably a short list). If the areas of antimagic don't function like the spell, all we can tell you is to ask your DM; and if you're looking for idea generation on homebrew/house-ruled solutions, such a question would be primarily opinion-based.

Comment: No. Im fairly certain there is nothing in any of the books that allows exceptions.  Im looking for any first hand accounts of players creating one, or adventures where a character experienced one, what they were and how it came about.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that your DM has the **magic dead-zones** there for a reason.

For one, these dead zones may not function in the same way as the 8th-level spell *Antimagic Field*. You need to ask your DM or find out as you adventure further into the campaign.

There is some information for antimagic field effects for Dead Magic zones (DMG p.109). If the these zones work in the same way, you do not have many options as per this previous post: 
[How to get rid of Anti-Magic Fields?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/138526/how-to-get-rid-of-anti-magic-fields)

However, even in this scenario, you could work try to work out a warning system to help you manage your way through a magic dead-zone. This way at least you have fair warning and don't find yourself in the midst of mob firing blanks!

For instance, let's suppose the dead zones are of an irregular shape and they do not cover the whole area you are in. But how can you know? In this case you might use a continual spell-effect on an object to serve as a warning to signal that you are going into a dead-zone. If you try casting a Cantrip you will find out without expending a spell slot, but that will use up your action, but this will get very tiresome.

You could use the 2nd-level spell **Continual Flame** on an object. For example, casting it on a fishing lure on the end of a very long fishing rod. Then just hold it out in front of you. When the lure hits the dead-zone it will repress the Continual Flame. Once you are back out of the zone it will light up again. :) ...**an antimagic radar** of sorts.

You could get more creative with this. Possibly train an animal companion wearing a collar with Continual Flame cast on it. You could cast it on an arrow and shoot it across a long distance to test the area, and so on.

But again, go back to the principle of why your DM has these zones in your campaign, respond to them creatively. See it as a challenge and have fun!

I hope this helps.

Comment: It may be worth noting that DMG p. 109 uses *antimagic field* effects for Dead Magic zones.

Comment: This makes the answer I was planning obsolete! I think that your first three sentences are the heart of the situation and might benefit from some extra emphasis-- this seems like a *plot element* rather than a *mechanical triviality* for PCs to deal with. If the only property an anti-magic field really has (suppressing magic) could be conveniently bypassed, there wouldn't be much point to including the field in the first place.

Comment: @Upper_Case Yeah, if it's an intentional part of the world that magic doesn't work everywhere, fighting against that is just going to be a waste of time.

Answer (score 2):

### Homebrew Problems require Homebrew Solutions

In-game solutions from another DM's game are unlikely to help you to help you. You're dealing with something your particular DM has created for their particular setting. You'll need to consult your DM for a homebrew or house rule solution. Nobody else can help you.

Comment: What makes you think the dead magic zones are homebrew? The GM could be using the Forgotten Realms setting, which traditionally includes many such zones as parts of "the weave."

Answer (score -3):

Spoilers for the Wheel of Time series inbound:

Off the top of my head, this sounds like your DM may be 'taking inspiration' (read: the time-honoured DM right of ripping off) from The Wheel of Time series' city of [Far Madding](https://wot.fandom.com/wiki/Far_Madding) where that universes magic users cannot wield their powers.

The in-universe solution is an item called a [Well](https://wot.fandom.com/wiki/Well), it holds a reserve of magical power that casters can tap into when Far Madding blocks them from casting in their usual fashion.

Talk to your DM about creating a reusable item such as a Well, or maybe single-use clay spell tokens or the like.

EDIT: @Vittorio Carano
[An actual in-universe spell-well](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Ring%20of%20Spell%20Storing#content)

Comment: Re: Homebrew/Homebrew. Absolutely, i am simply attempting to crowdsource for innovative possibilities outside my own head.

Comment: @VittorioCarano Stack Exchange is for finding the one best answer, not idea generation. You may have better success with a more traditional conversation forum.

Comment: Well. This is what i am looking for, i think. Also, it was not my intention to brainstorm, i simply wanted to know if anyone has dealt with campaigns with far reaching anti magic zones, and if they had successfully found ingame ways to circumvent them, besides avoidance. I appreciate everyones input.

Comment: @VittorioCarano Found an actual item, answer updated.

Comment: @Conor Under D&D rules, a *ring of spell storing* is no more powerful than a small lump of metal inside an anti-magic field.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Relevant meta: [Don't signal your edits in text](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3454/dont-signal-your-edits-in-text). Instead, you should edit your answer to read as if it were always the best version of itself. In addition, as TJL points out, the *ring of spell-storing* does not function in an area of antimagic.